# Why doesn't the Script Task code assign any value to ReadWriteVariables?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to assign a value to the variable *`User::PrevMonth`* of data type *`String`* using *`Script Task`* but no value is being set. The variable has not been set with any value on the *`Variables`* properties pane.

[image: Variables]

My script task has been setup in my *Control Flow*. In the properties of the *Script Task*, I have set two variables as *`ReadWriteVariables`*. The other variable seems to be working fine and they are declared as *`Int32`*

[image: Script Task Editor]

#### Here is my Script Task code:

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_7206cd3a4d734228b8d6860bdb6a59c9.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion
        public void Main()
        {
            //This will get the year as an int (e.g. 2013)
            DateTime dLastYear = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
            int iLastYear = dLastYear.Year;

            //This will get the month as an str (e.g. 04)
            DateTime dLastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
            string sLastMonth = dLastMonth.ToString("MM");
            
            //Assign variables back to SSIS package
            Dts.Variables["User::PrevMonth"].Value = sLastMonth;
            Dts.Variables["User::Year"].Value = iLastYear;

            //Return package success
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

The variable with String data type does not change its value after successful execution of the package. This is really bugging me I feel like I've checked everything.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing? I'm guessing it's something really stupid/obvious.

#### Update:

I've used *`Message Box`* inside the `Script Task` to view the variable values and they're displaying the correct output.

Comment: Any chance you have two copies of the variables defined? One at the control flow, on the Script Task?

Comment: Also, try tossing a message box in there to emit the values of sLastMonth and iLastYear. Perhaps your logic off.

Comment: I've put in an edit, but I've done that and they seem to be fine.

Comment: How do I check for two copies of variables being defined? I did delete the variable and re-add. I've screenshotted my variable window...

Comment: I am running the package now (Takes an hour or two) but I will try this when it becomes available. For now I've manually inputted the variable. Will comment once I've tried it.

Comment: How are you determining that the values are not being set? Seems a silly question, I know but the value of a variable in the Variables window will *not* change during execution. That's a design time thing. The *actual* value is available from the `Locals` window of the Debug, Windows, Locals menu. Expand Variables there and then you can inspect the run-time values.

Comment: Billinkc, I have a scary suspicion that what you just said is my mistake... I need a little time before I can check it over though as I've got the package running. Do you want to submit your comment as an answer and I will mark correct if that turns out to be the case.

Comment: No worries if that's the case. I think we've all stumbled on that one before and now we should have an authoritative question and answer for future seekers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply building on my comment about Variables window versus Locals

> How are you determining that the values are not being set? Seems a
>   silly question, I know but the value of a variable in the Variables
>   window will not change during execution. That's a design time thing.
>   The actual value is available from the Locals window of the Debug,
>   Windows, Locals menu. Expand Variables there and then you can inspect
>   the run-time values

Given a package as simple as this

[image: simple control flow, script task to script task]

This is an example showing the *actual* value in my package versus what is *still* reported in the Variables window. Technically, I set a Watch on those two variables as the actual Locals window has a lot of "noise" in it with all of the System variables.

[image: watch versus variables window]

An example of the Locals window

[image: Locals window]

So, I see and I think Siva (now user756519) concurs that your script is working and correctly assigning the value to the variables during run-time so perhaps there is something else in your package that is amiss. It may be that you are not using those variables where you think you are.

Answer (score 3):

#### How to view variables declared under multiple package scopes in BIDS

This is a response to your comment and ***`not`*** an answer to your question.

```
How do I check for two copies of variables being defined? 
I did delete the variable and re-add. I've screenshotted my variable window.
```

Here is a sample SSIS package created in *`BIDS 2008 R2`*. The package has a *`Script Task`*. I have declared two variables under different scopes but with the same name **`PrevMonth`**

- *First* variable is declared under the package scope **`SO_14857540`**
- *Second* variable is declared under the task scope **`Script Task`**

When the package is selected, the variables pane will only display the package variables declared under the package scope.

[image: Package variable]

To view all the variables declared under different scopes, click the *fourth* icon on the *`Variables`* properties pane. It should have the tool tip text **`Show All Variables`**.

[image: All variabls]

However, this *could* be a reason for the appearance of a variable value "not" changing. The PrevMonth that is scoped to SO_14857540 and thus is visible to the entire package. The PrevMonth that is scoped to "Script Task". When the script task executes, the locally scoped variable will be visible. Your script task will change the value of the locally scoped variable and then *that* variable goes out of scope and only the package scoped variable remains.

Answer (score 0):

Wrestling with an issue like this today, I found that if the variable has an Expression (in my case, it was a default value that the script task changes in certain circumstances), the Expression always overwrites whatever you are writing to the variable: remove the expression and the script task sets the value correctly.