# SSIS - attempting to assign a variable in postexecute not working?

Tags: ssis

I am building an SSIS package consisting of some dataflow tasks that contain script components.  In one of these script components I'm trying to assign a value to a read/write variable in the post execute sub as follows:

```
Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
    Me.ReadWriteVariables("User::pEndDate").Value() = proEndDate
    MyBase.PostExecute()
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    ...

    Try
        ...
        proEndDate = Row.EndDate
        MessageBox.Show("Assigning the project end date from the row: " & proEndDate.ToString)
```

proEndDate has the correct value in it per the message box, but the variable is never being updated.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the Script Task code assign any value to ReadWriteVariables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857540/why-doesnt-the-script-task-code-assign-any-value-to-readwritevariables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The variable is never being updated". I take it this means when you look at the Variable's window while the package is running, the value never changes from its original.

This is correct and the value will never change but your code is also correct.

The Variables window shows the Design-time value of all of your variables. The *Run-time* values are accessible through the Debug window. In your Local's window, you will see the current value. I wrote a more detailed answer over here

[Why doesn't the Script Task code assign any value to ReadWriteVariables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857540/why-doesnt-the-script-task-code-assign-any-value-to-readwritevariables/14858322#14858322)